# How to automatically redirect from one page to another within a few seconds

Tags: java, wicket

The idea is to display a `PageExpiredPage` that is **visible for a few seconds** and **automatically redirects** to the `HomePage`, when the *web session expires*.

By the following code the `PageExpiredPage` displays with a bookmarkable link to the `HomePage` on it.

> PageExpiredPage.html:

```
Your session expired, log in anew by clicking
<a wicket:id="lnk-home-page" href="#"> here</a>
...
```

> PageExpiredPage.java:

```
final Application app = Session.get().getApplication();
BookmarkablePageLink<? extends Page> lnkHomePage = new BookmarkablePageLink<? extends Page>("lnk-home-page", app.getHomePage());
add(lnkHomePage);
...
```

How to code in Wicket that the `PageExpiredPage`, when displayed, automatically redirects to `HomePage` after a configurable number of seconds?

Comment: You could do this pretty simply using Javascript on the 'expired' page, though obviously that requires the user to have Javascript enabled. Any reason you haven't considered this?

Comment: @Anthony I would like Wicket to do the Javascript and code it in Java. One reason is that he URL coding strategy could change. If this happens or you change your home page to another class, every time you would have to update the Javascript on the 'expired' page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A better solution than the RedirectPage is a custom behaviour. The obvious problem with RedirectPage is that you can't use a common base class for the layout of the page.

```
public class RedirectBehavior extends Behavior {

    private final Class<? extends Page> page;
    private final int redirectInSeconds;

    public RedirectBehavior(Class<? extends Page> page, int redirectInSeconds) {
        this.page = page;
        this.redirectInSeconds = redirectInSeconds;
    }

    @Override
    public void renderHead(Component component, IHeaderResponse response) {
        response.renderString(String.format("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='%d;URL=%s' />", redirectInSeconds,
                RequestCycle.get().urlFor(page, null)));
    }
}
```

This way you can pass the return value from `getHomePage()` directly - no need for `newInstance()`:

```
public class PageExpiredPage extends YourBasePage {
    public PageExpiredPage () {
        add(new RedirectBehavior(Application.get().getHomePage(), 5));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I may have missed something, but it seems to me that [`RedirectPage`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/pages/RedirectPage.html) can do just that:

> Page that let the browser redirect. Use this if you want to direct the browser to some external URL, like Google etc. **or if you want to redirect to a Wicket page, but with a delay.** (my emphasis)

Constructor:

```
RedirectPage(Page page, int waitBeforeRedirectInSeconds)
```

`RedirectPage` extends `org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage` and accepts a `org.apache.wicket.Page` as first argument.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The reason why I not picked that solution was that Session.get().getApplication().getHomePage() returns the type Class<? extends Page>, not Page.
- Rethinking it, I think the solution is to add another method to the WebApplication implementation like getHomePageInstance() and cast ((MyWebApplication)Session.get().getApplication()).getHomePageInstance(). - Using Class.newInstance() seems ugly.